# MVVM - Global actions that act on the "currently selected object"

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, mvvm

I have a complex application that I am attempting to develop using MVVM (a pattern that I am new to) - the applicaton has tabs and docked windows each of which has the concept of a "selected object", and a global toolbar at the top of the application that has actions on it that need to act on the "selected object".

Imagine a slightly less complicated version of something similar to Visual Studio, for example:

- If a pane is selected that contains a list view where the selected object is "inactive" then the "Activate" toolbar item should be enabled. (The global selected item is that list view item)
- If however the user then clicks on a tab in another pane which has no selected object then that same toolbar item should be disabled (The global selected item is null).

Ignoring for the moment complications such as multiple selections, at the moment I have implemented this by creating an all-encompassing singleton* model class that represents the "application" itself, e.g.

```
class MyAppModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ISelectableObject SelectedObject { get; }
}
```

I then have "a system" (I admit I'm glossing over a lot of details here) in place for making sure that this property is updated (and the relevent events fired) when changes in the UI results in changes in the global "currently selected object", and the toolbar buttons use this property to determine availability etc...

However I'm getting hung up on the fact that this doesn't seem very MVVM-like (I read somewhere that UI state should be stored in the ViewModel?)

- Is having a global model that represents "the application" in this way a good idea? (there are also other properties on there to keep track of other things in the application in a similar way, such as the open documents)
- If not, what should I use instead to allow global components (such as items in the toolbar) to find out and keep track of what the "global selected object" is

---

(*) Which could just as easily be supplied using dependency injection

Answer (score 0):

for `MVVM` you should definately have a master `ViewModel` that represents the top-level binding surface for your `Views`.That master `ViewModel` will have a `'SelectedItem'` property that participates in the `INotifyPropertyChanged` notifications of the `ViewModel`. You should then bind your relevant ItemsControl(s) (`TabControl` etc) `SeledctedItem` to this `ViewModel` Property, then other parts of your app can bind to the ViewModels `SelectedItem` property and bindings will change automatically.

Comment: How should other parts of the application obtain this ViewModel? My menu items are implemented as separate classes that implement a common interface (e.g. the [`ICommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.aspx) interface - how do they get hold of the application ViewModel?

Comment: Your ICommand implementations should be properties on your main viewModel

Comment: Thats not really possible as some commands are defined externally and discovered at runtime when the menu is constructed (e.g. plugins that expose menu options).

Comment: In MVVM your Menu should bind to your viewmodel, and your viewmodel should calcualte and expose the binsings necesary for the menu to construct itself

Answer (score 0):

try to register PreNotifyInput event of Inputmanager.current. and register this at applicaiton level this event into global level.

```
InputManager.Current.PreNotifyInput += new NotifyInputEventHandler(Current_PreNotifyInput);
```

also refer to Inputmanager class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms617136

Comment: Huh? I don't understand how this answers the question of "should I have a global model representing 'the application'"